# How std::initializer_list Works?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently studying c++11 i did not understand constructor of std::initializer_list it looks like this

```
constexpr initializer_list() noexcept : _First(nullptr), _Last(nullptr) {}

constexpr initializer_list(const _Elem* _First_arg, const _Elem* _Last_arg) noexcept
    : _First(_First_arg), _Last(_Last_arg) {}
```

But How it works with

```
std::initializer_list<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
```

and i tried this

```
constexpr init(const _Elem* _First_arg, const _Elem* _Last_arg) noexcept
    : _First(_First_arg), _Last(_Last_arg) {}
```

but this shows error

```
init<int> ob{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}; //this shows error

 note: candidate: 'constexpr init<_Elem>::init(const _Elem*, const _Elem*) [with _Elem = int]'
 constexpr init(const _Elem* _First_arg, const _Elem* _Last_arg) noexcept
           ^~~~
 note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 10 provided
```

and i changed {} to () like

```
std::initializer_list<int> v(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
```

This shows error.

1)How std::initializer_list works?

2)What is behind {} ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` is special. It is impossible to write a class that could be used as a constructor argument in the same way. The language rules specify how `std::initializer_list` works - or rather, how constructors that accept `std::initializer_list` i.e. *initializer-list constructors* work. And the language implementation makes it work as specified.

P.S. Identifiers such as `_Elem` are reserved to the language implementation. Since your class `init` is not part of the language implementation, using reserved identifiers results in undefined behaviour. Don't use reserved identifiers.