# Why we need a private constructor for std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, stdinitializerlist

The suggested implementation of `std::initializer_list` in [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.initlist#initializer.list.syn) and [The C++ Programming Language](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) are simple. By simple I mean there is nothing strange.
But things become complex in the Compilers implementation of `std::initializer_list`, for example, GCC has a private constructor for `std::initializer_list` with a comment above it which says: ['*The compiler can call a private constructor.*'](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/initializer_list#L61).
Here [eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62448360/9248466) answered:*`std::initializer_list` is special.* So I looked for it in the compilers source code:

### Clang:

- [AST/ExprCXX.h#L789](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/61cdaf66fe22be2b5942ddee4f46a998b4f3ee29/clang/lib/AST/StmtPrinter.cpp#L1935)
- [AST/StmtPrinter.cpp#L1935](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/61cdaf66fe22be2b5942ddee4f46a998b4f3ee29/clang/lib/AST/StmtPrinter.cpp#L1935)
- [AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp#4523](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/92dcb1d2db8c4de48df0af806dca631523cd4169/clang/lib/AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp#L4523)

### GCC:

- [cp/cp-tree.h#L2303](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/cp/cp-tree.h#L2303)
- [cp/init.c#L702](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/cp/init.c#L702)
- [cp/call.c#L801](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/cp/call.c#L801)

And I don't understand why do we need to have a special private constructor? I encountered this some time ago when I wanted to convert `std::vector<T>` to `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Comment: IMHO, this is to stop people from using `std::initializer_list` incorrectly.  You really should only create a `std::initializer_list` by copying one, or by having it implicitly created from a  `{ list, of, values, ... }`.  If a type is constructible from a `std::initializer_list` it should also have a constructor that takes an iterator range so it can be constructed from any "list" of values.

Comment: Do you mean the only reason for this is API safety?

Comment: More so correctness safety.  A `std::initializer_list` is used to model `{ an, intializer, list, ...} `.  It is backed by a temporary array that the compiler creates for us, and then it takes care of destroying that array when the `std::initializer_list` object is destroyed.  If you could access the  `initializer_list(const_iterator __a, size_type __l)` constructor then you could have it point to something that isn't an initializer list and memory that is not controlled by the compiler.

Comment: *"By simple I mean there is nothing strange."* `std::initializer_list` is special, regular user cannot implement it.  From linked synopsis, only a default constructor...

Comment: Exactly. `std::initializer_list` is a reification of an initializer list; it’s not supposed to exist in other circumstances. In particular you’re not meant to construct one from code in order to unify two use cases.

Comment: There is a `gsl::span` (or `std::span` in C++20) for the purpose you seem to want and (ab)use `std::initializer_list` for. It's a support type for `{...}` initialization, not a contiguous range abstractor. The types I mentioned exist for this purpose.

Comment: Okay, I got really confused. If it's special, why do we have a header file for it in the STL? It couldn't just be directly handled by the compiler itself?  I mean something like a new keyword for it?

Comment: Why add a new keyword and potentially break existing code, when the library has a namespace?

Comment: BTW, remember too that the standard headers don't require to be files (or even regular headers).

Answer (score 5):

The `std::initializer_list` is a reification of actual initializer-list, and its constructor is `private` simply to ensure no one is ever able to call it (except the compiler, of course), which prevents people from using `std::initializer_list` incorrectly.

As mentioned by [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica);
There is a `gsl::span` (or `std::span` in C++20) for contiguous range abstraction purpose. But it seems you try to (ab)use `std::initializer_list` for that instead. 
(Which you can not as that is just a support type for `{...}` initialization.)

---

From comments:

> ... Couldn't it just be directly handled by the compiler itself? I mean something like a new keyword for it?

Well, a new keyword would potentially break existing codes, but the `std` namespace is a pretty safe place (for preventing conflicts).